Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k}=n 2^{n-1}$
I am trying to find a combinatorial proof of the following identity
$\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k}=n 2^{n-1}$.
Let $S$ be a set with $n$ elements.
The idea would be to find two different ways to count on how many possibilities there are to choose a subset with a specific element in it.
Counting 1:
Choose the specifict element $e$ first ($n$ possibilities) and then just chose a subset $A \subseteq S \setminus {e}$ ($2^{n-1} $possibilities) and then define $T:=A \cup \{e\}$.
Thus we would get $n 2^{n-1} $possibilities.
Counting 2:
I am not really sure on how to continue from here on.
The factor $k \binom{n}{k}$ would indicate that I consider all $k$-subsets of $S$ and then choose one element to get $k \binom{n}{k}$.
But I don't know why one would do a sum.
Because if I sum over "all subsets of size $k$" and choose one element per subset (to get the factor $k$) I would end up with more than one "specific" element.
If someone would have a solution to this and could explain it to me, that would be great.

Consider a committee of $n$ members.  Count how many ways there are to choose a subcommittee of any size with a committee chair by (1) Choosing the chair first and then picking who else (if any) serve on the sub committee... or (2) Break into cases based on the size of the subcommittee and from there choosing the subcommittee of that size first and picking someone from that to serve as chair.
